# Is the use of the $GLOBALS array in Drupal in anyway 'less secure' or 'bad practice'?

Tags: users

Is the use of the $GLOBALS array in Drupal in anyway 'less secure' or 'bad practice'. Like using:

```
$GLOBALS['user']->uid
```

instead of

```
$account->uid
```

if it were avialable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no it is not bad practice or insecure, it is fine to use the $user global.
Drupal core and a huge amount of modules use the $user global.

If you want to be really picky though:

However, it is possible for you to install bad code into your site somewhere that puts bad things into the $user global.

That is just a risk in general though with putting any code on your site, it doesn't just relate to the $user global.

Also, for all I know the $account variable you talk about could be bad because I have no idea where that variable is coming from as your question doesn't detail it.

Answer (score 3):

Directing using

```
global $user
$user->uid
```

adds a new variable to your current scope, which adds potential for misuse and other accidents.

Using

```
$GLOBALS['user']->uid
```

can be seen as a safety precaution.  You can still mess things up, but it is somewhat harder, and you don't introduce a new variable.

However, directly poking around in the `$user` object is bad in a lot of cases, especially explicitly using `$user->uid`.

Whenever possible, you should leverage the API.  For example, use

```
if (user_is_logged_in()) { ... }
```

instead of

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid) { ... }
```

and use [`user_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7) instead of using `$user->roles`.

One place where explicit `$user->uid` use may be needed is with database queries, though that can be lessened somewhat with `EntityFieldQuery->addAccount` and `db_select->addtag('node_access')`.